# Disabling JavaFX ComboBox input

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

How do I disable input on my editable Combobox? (Well, actually JFoenix JFXCombobox but it's basically the same apart from it's appearance)

`setEditable(false)` would disable keyboard input on the Combobox but the list would still appear

`setDisabled(true)` would disable whole Combobox but I want user to be able to focus Combobox so he can copy it's contents if necessery.

**Why do I want it like that?** In my forms user must first click edit button to be able to change stuff.

Comment: Cant test it at the moment, but try `yourComboBox.getEditor().setEditable(false)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the method [`ComboBox.setEditable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#setEditable-boolean-) adds/removes an Editor to the ComboBox which can be retrieved via [`ComboBox.getEditor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#getEditor--)

To keep the TextField (to copy from) but disable user-input, simply set the `editable` flag on the underlying TextField:

```java
private ComboBox<String> myComboBox;
[...]

myComboBox.setEditable(true);
myComboBox.getEditor().setEditable(false);
```

EDIT:

As @jewelsea said in a comment below, you can hide the list as soon as the user requests to open it:

```java
myComboBox.setOnShown(event -> comboBox.hide());
```

I think it would be "cleaner" to disable the button which opens the dropdown but unfortunately I have not yet found a way to do that.

Comment: Clever, but I believe the OP also wants to stop the user from displaying the drop down: "_[...] would disable keyboard input on the Combobox **but the list would still appear**_".

Comment: @Slaw also do, `myComboBox.setOnShown(event -> comboBox.hide());` to stop the list appearing.

Comment: Thank you @jewelsea , I added your code to my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. So it's a whole lot easier than I expected, I thought I would have to extend the Combobox and dig deeper